# Android Hijacking My Star Character

Tags: android, html, css, frontend

So I ran into an interesting problem when working on an e-commerce responsive design.

We're using the HTML star character to display our ratings as opposed to images. We, like most, use the solid star for a filled in star, and a hollow one to indicate it's not.

Like this: ★★★☆☆

Android is hijaking the filled in character, but not the hollow one. In doing so it's increasing the width, causing layout issues.

Is there a way to override their override (ew)?

Here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing on a Galaxy S5.
[image: S5Screenshot]

Comment: Unless you are controlling the Font Face, there's no guarantee *exactly* how the stars will look. They look different from each other here in your question on Chrome on Windows, with the font stack that Stack Overflow uses, for instance.

Comment: Yes, I understand that different fonts will display differently, and some may not even include these obscure characters. What's interesting is that it's showing what appears to be an image in its place, and it's increasing the size of the filled in star, which on all other devices and browsers are the same size (filled in should be a gold/orange color.)

Comment: I also just tested on a Google Nexus phone, and it's displaying as it should.. this could just be an issue unique to Samsung, or even the s5. It is appearing this way both in chrome and the default android browser.

Comment: They aren't the same size on my chrome/Windows, either. And they aren't images; they are text... that's just what they look like. I'm pasting the stars in here from my own s5 here: ★★★☆☆